# Using sed to delete lines from list variable

Tags: sed

I have a script which uses sed in a loop to delete lines containing words from a list:

```
for i in $list; do
  sed -i "/$i/d" file
done
```

`$list` is created from an SQL query:

```
list=$(psql -d dbname -t -c "SELECT foo from table ORDER BY column DESC")
```

The problem is my company recently implemented tighter auditd rules which include all `fchown` or `fchmod` syscalls.  Using `strace`, I see every `sed -i` includes one `fchown` and `fchmod` syscall.

With a large list variable, `iowait` skyrockets and the system actually bogs down because auditd is writing a ridiculous amount of lines to its log.

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to pass the list variable to sed in one line so the file is only opened and closed once.

I've already asked, any changes to the auditd rules is a non-starter.

Thanks.

Comment: What's `$list` ? Is it a list of words saved in a file, one per line or an array or what ?

Comment: `$list` is one word per line.

Comment: From where do you get list? If all the words or patterns are in a file line by line you could use `fgrep -v -f patternfile inputfile > file && mv tmpfile file` of `grep ...` if you have regex patterns.

Comment: You could try to convert your list in a string in that way, that the final `sed` command that is exceuted looks like this: `sed -i -E "/(word1|word2|word3)/d" file`

Comment: I added how the list is created to the post.  I was wrong earlier, it's not one word per line, rather words separated by a single space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By only running `sed` once and using a single `sed` script rather than invoking a zillion in-line commands one-by-one:

```
sedscript=$(mktemp)
for i in $list; do
  echo "/$i/d" >> "$sedscript"
done
sed -f "$sedscript" -i /path/to/file
rm -f "$sedscript"
```

Comment: I'm liking this solution, but I'm getting `sed: can't find label for jump to 'mp.Vbqh8BAFGv'`  The 't' is getting dropped from the mktemp filename somewhere.

Comment: This works without creating a temp file:
`sedscript=$(for i in $list; do echo "/$i/d"; done)  
&& sed -e "$sedscript" -i /path/to/file'`

Comment: My mistake; `sed -e` should have been `sed -f`; `-e` is "run this command right here" (which is implied by default), while `-f` is "run the commands in this file".

Answer (score 1):

If you can carefully assign the words in `list`, you could use bash parameter expansion to replace every space with the regex alternator `|`, then ask `grep` to do the work for you:

```
list='auditd the to'
cp file temp &&  
grep -Ev "${list// /|}" temp > file && 
rm temp
```

Comment: This relies on the assumption (also present in your `sed` example) that none of the "list" values contain regular expression tokens (that you didn't expect).

Answer (score 0):

If this: `psql -d dbname -t -c "SELECT foo from table ORDER BY column DESC"` gives you a white-space delimited list of words, try this:

```
$ psql -d dbname -t -c "SELECT foo from table ORDER BY column DESC" \
| awk -v FS=" " -v OFS="|" '{$1=$1; print "("$0")"}' \
| xargs -I {} sed -i -E '/{}/d' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If your shell supports arrays, you  could do something like

```
mapfile -t arr < <(psql -d dbname -t -c "SELECT foo from table ORDER BY column DESC")
```

to put the output of the command into a shell array, then

```
printf '/%s/d\n' "${arr[@]}" | sed -i.bak -f - somefile
```

to apply the sequence of deletions to `somefile`, in place. The usual caveats apply if the fields returned from your `psql` command might contain characters that are special to `sed`.

This is similar to @DopeGhoti's solution, except that it avoids the temporary script file (and should handle whitespace in table fields, should that be necessary).